# build tensorflow 1.4 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: tensorflow

I am following [the instructions here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), and this step:

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

fails with:

> ....... ERROR:
>   /home/ruben/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruben/d7b0d5278ead13c4c0b0dbae55902502/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/BUILD:5686:1:
>   @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-nvvm: illegal output file name
>   'cuda/nvvm/espeak-ng-data/voices/!v/max' in rule
>   @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-nvvm: invalid target name
>   'cuda/nvvm/espeak-ng-data/voices/!v/max': target names may not contain
>   '!' ERROR:
>   /home/ruben/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ruben/d7b0d5278ead13c4c0b0dbae55902502/external/local_config_cuda/cuda/BUILD:5686:1:
>   @local_config_cuda//cuda:cuda-nvvm: missing value for mandatory
>   attribute 'outs' in 'genrule' rule ERROR:
>   /home/ruben/Documents/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:2953:1:
>   Target '@local_config_cuda//cuda:darwin' contains an error and its
>   package is in error and referenced by
>   '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' ERROR:
>   /home/ruben/Documents/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:2953:1:
>   Target '@local_config_cuda//cuda:darwin' contains an error and its
>   package is in error and referenced by
>   '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' ERROR: Analysis
>   of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed;
>   build aborted: Loading failed INFO: Elapsed time: 75.399s FAILED:
>   Build did NOT complete successfully (77 packages loaded)
>       currently loading: tensorflow/core/kernels

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you please add the following information: How did you configure tensorflow? Which compiler, CUDA and CuDNN version do you use?

Comment: CUDA 8, CuDNN 6 both installed using packages downloaded from NVIDIA website. I configured tensorflow using the same instruction shown in the link I gave. Used the same options.